# Show the Texts in Mobile App Which is Written in Admin Panel

Tags: android, html, ios, markdown

We have a mobile application which pulls all the datas inside the app from our restfull webservices.
And these webservices gets the datas which is created by our admin panel.
Now we want to add some text in our admin panel via a text editor and show these texts in our mobile applications.
But we want our text editor to have bold, italic, spacces, quoates etc.. capabilities.
For acomplishing this I think we need to use a text standart which is available in both IOS, Android and Web.
Markdown standart and markdown editors seemed a correct choice for this. But I dont know if I can use any other thing?
For the text editor, I would like to use a free html/javascript editor

What will be your suggestions about that?

Comment: This sort of "What third party library should I use" question is not a good fit for SO.

Comment: iOS and Android both natively support web views, as Yogesh suggests. Another option might be using an rtf file, assuming Android has the ability to display those. (On iOS there is framework support for loading rich text from an rtf file into a `UITextView`)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the document in html fomat from Admin Panel & show that in WebView in your app.

by using in app :

```
webView.loadData(myHtmlString, "text/html", null);
```

Comment: But how can I save a regular text (with bold, italic etc... parameters) in html format?

Comment: use <b>Your text</b> fir bold
<i>Tour text</i> for italic

Comment: If I go into that kind of details, I wouldnt need html, I can simply convert it to any format I want, but its too much work. What I need is use an open source editor and use its output in our mobile app